# I met a beggar in New York

Tags: parts-of-speech

1. I met him in New York.
2. I met a beggar in New York.
3. I met the beggar in New York.

---

What is the part of speech of 'in New York'? Is it an adjective phrase or an adverbial phrase? Or can it be both?

My explanation for #2 is as follows.

Where did you meet a beggar? I met a beggar in New York. If this is the answer to the question, in Sentence 2, 'in New York' is an adverbial phrase.

Which person did you meet? I met a beggar in New York. (This one means I met a beggar who was in New York.) In this cases, 'in New York' is an adjective phrase. There are many beggars in New York. And I met a beggar of all the beggars in New York.

What do you think about my explanation?

Answer (score 2):

In all three of your sentences, a normal reading would understand "in New York" to be a statement about where you *met* the person. (Adverbial prepositional phrase.)

*"I met a beggar in New York. He told me he was trying to raise money for a bus ticket home to Poughkeepsie."*

*"I met the beggar in New York.  After getting to know him, we discovered that we had grown up down the street from each other in Dallas."*

If you wanted to say that you met a beggar who calls New York home, you would say *"I met a beggar from New York."*  This could have happened elsewhere: *"While waiting to board the airplane in Newark, I met a beggar from New York."*

If you want to say that you met one of that famous group of beggars who collectively inhabit New York, and who have formed some sort of group identity or mystique *(The Beggars of New York)* you might say *"I met a Beggar of New York."*

Comment: And note that *from New York* would be adjectival.